# fastAPI pass websocket to an endpoint with other parameters

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I have a fast api with many endpoints, one of them I want to pass a websocket and communicate with it. The problem is that all the working examples online pass the socket to `localhost:8000/ws` serving no other purpose other than communicating through the socket, but what I'm trying to do is pass the socket to a function with other parameters and send data through it, but that's where i get an error.

**main.py**

```
@app.post("/file_upload")

async def file_upload(
      data: UploadFile, name: str, user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_authenticated_user)], ws: WebSocket
):
""" docs for swagger ... """

try:
        await ws.Accept()
        path, size = await utils.save_file(data, ws) # in the save_file function ill be uploading or downloading the file locally and also sending progress to js through websocket
except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Could not create file: %s", e)
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail="There was an error uploading the file",
        )

    return {"file_path": path}
```

as you can see my end goal is to send progress throughout the upload, and display it in js

**utils.save_file()**

```
async def save_file(data: UploadFile, ws:WebSocket = None) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    """save a zip file."""
    local_filepath = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, f"data_{gen_random_filename()}.zip")
    # upload a zip file

    total_size = data.size
    size = 0
    CHUNK = 64 * 1024 * 1024  # 64MB
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open(local_filepath, "wb") as f:
            while contents := await data.read(CHUNK):
                await f.write(contents)
                size += len(contents)
                print(f'{size} / {total_size}')
                global progress
                progress = {"progress": int(size / total_size * 100)}

                await ws.send_text(json.dumps(data))
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Could not save file: %s", e)
        raise Exception("Could not write data to the local file")
    finally:
        await data.close()

    return local_filepath, size
```

the logic in this file is correct and it's not causing any errors
**index.js**

```
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/file_upload");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                console.log(event.data)
            };
```

so i guess the issue is first caught here, js tries to open connection with the end point `file_upload` but its function takes more than just a socket, and so it fails.

Comment: "serving no other purpose other than communicating through the socket" is kinda what a websocket does. You can't create a websocket endpoint in FastAPI without using `@app.websocket`

Comment: sure i've made the `@app.websocket` and connected to is successfully. but can i pass the socket to other endpoints?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the socket to other endpoints"?

Comment: checkout `@app.post("/file_upload")` (the last parameter) i want `file_upload(data,  name..., websocket)` to send messages through the socket so it must have access to it, but passing it through the parameter (like in my code) conflicts with the JavaScript code initializing the socket

Comment: Nope, that's not how HTTP and websockets work.